# Dynamically access object property using passed down prop as variable, on Vue 2 & Vuex returns error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've tried for a few hours already to fix this problem and I can't manage to do so. I've checked these 2 questions but they didn't help me:

[Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

[Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

The only thing that it could be is the answer of @chacham15 that says "careful with this: javascript compilers will error here since they dont rename strings but they do rename object properties".

If that's the case, how do I solve this?

My objective is to access the `this.$store.state.countries.spain.name` property dynamically, so it would access spain, germany, and so on. I've tried everything:

```
this.$store.state.countries[""+name].name
this.$store.state.countries[this.name].name
this.$store.state.countries[name].name
this.$store.state.countries[`${this.name}`].name
this.$store.state.countries[`${name}`].name
```

I've also tried making a function that takes the `name` variable and assigns it to a const variable inside the function, and nothing. The `name` variable is a string, and I can `console.log` it properly without issues, that's why I don't understand what's happening.

It only returns the property when I use `this.$store.state.countries["spain"].name`, so I know the property exists and it can return with no error. My problem is when I try to access the property using a variable.

This is the code:

```
<template>
    <tr class="stats-row">
        <td :title="`${name}`">{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{this.$store.state.countries[this.name]}}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
        
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
        
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'StatsRow',
    components: {
    },
    props: {
        name: String,
    },
});
    
</script>
```

And this is the parent Vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="stats">
        <table>
            <StatsRow v-for="el in this.$store.state.countries" v-bind:key="el.name" :name="el.name"/>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import StatsRow from '@/components/StatsRow.vue';
    
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Stats',
        components: {
        StatsRow,
    },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your main and only problem is that you are using `this` inside templates. Everything in the Vue templates is implicitly looked up in `this` (Vue component instance). Stop doing that and your code should work just fine...

Comment: Do you mean the ``this.name`` or the ``this.$store.state.countries``? If it's the latter, how do you use it without the ``this``? If you meant the ``this.name``, I also tried using ``name`` alone, and it didn't work

Comment: I mean every `this` in the template. `how do you use it without the this?` ...just remove every `this.` from the template...

Comment: I just tried, and it didn't work either. I tried ``$store.state.countries[name].name``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by sending all of the elements as props from the parent.

This is the child:

```
<template>
  <tr class="stats-row">
    <td :title="`${name}`">{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{newCases}}</td>
    <td>{{totalCases}}</td>
    <td>{{newDeaths}}</td>
    <td>{{totalDeaths}}</td>
    <td>{{newRecovered}}</td>
    <td>{{totalRecovered}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

This is the parent:

```
<template>
  <div class="stats">
    <table>
      <StatsRow v-for="el in this.$store.state.countries" v-bind:key="el.name" :active="el.active"   :name="el.name" :color="el.color" :showCases="el.showCases" :showDeaths="el.showDeaths" :newCases="el.newCases" :totalCases="el.totalCases" :newDeaths="el.newDeaths" :totalDeaths="el.totalDeaths" :newRecovered="el.newRecovered" :totalRecovered="el.totalRecovered"/>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```